# How to Create or Assign roles and resources from a web page in Jazn-data.xml file in Adf fusion Application

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have made a fusion web application in Oracle Jdeveloper 11g used Oracle plateform security services(OPSS) for authentication and authriztion Made LoginBean..created login,error and welcome page, and also created menu, given access to the page and menu to the different roles (roles like SuperAdmin, CompanyAdmin, Manager, and User)created in the Jazn-data.xml file..Now what i want that instead of creating Enterprise, Application roles and custom resources for controlling the UI components(hiding and unhiding of menu etc) directly from the Jazn file the same Operation can be done through a web page in the application whose access can be give to the admin and he can directly create users, roles and resources and assign them to different users and application roles from the web page.

Is there any way so that we can perform all the activities like creating users, roles, resources and assignment through a web page in the jazn-data.xml file in adf fusion application ???

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write a Web page that communicates with the API exposed by your security repository to manage users/roles.
Here is an example with OID - http://ramannanda.blogspot.com/2011/09/opss-adf-security-utility.html

Comment: Thank you shay...but i want to get all the roles and resources of all the the user not only of the Logged in user...How can i do the same..?? I am also not using LDAp for identity management..right now..

Answer (score 0):

The method is already there getAllUserRoles will fetch all the roles. Also i think you mean you are not using OID rather than LDAP(because it is just a protocol). You can use the embedded ldap provider just switch the implementation class to weblogic provider class instead of OID.